# Best Way to Display "Unsupported" Browser Message

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

We are working on a web application which only supports "modern" browsers (basically IE9 and up, and any other browser which has roughly the same amount of modern features).

Our web application will also work on mobile devices like tablets and smartphones.

Since this is a web application (as opposed to a normal website), we are okay with some users being left out in the cold for some of the advanced features which rely on modern features (i.e., older browsers).

However, we want to at least display a message letting them know.

We want to maintain basically two lists: "supported browsers" and "unsupported browsers", with a third implicit list "not supported browsers" (i.e., browsers that are on neither least).

- If the browser was on the supported list, we wouldn't show anything.
- If it is on the "unsupported" list, it will always show a message which says "This browser is unsupported, please upgrade blah blah".
- If the browser is not in either, it will display a message (which can be almost-permanently dismissed) which says something like "This browser isn't tested directly against our site and some features may not function as intended. If you experience any issues, please report them blah blah".

Building this and what not isn't an issue. However, I was wondering if there was some site/service out there with an API that already did this sort of thing, or at least maintained lists of browsers which I could pull from. (If not, I just plan to use manual testing combined with info from sites like "Can I use..." and Modernizr).

Any ideas?

Comment: "unsupported browsers" and "not supported browsers", or how to make a nightmare of another developer's life :D

Comment: Bad idea: What would you consider to be a 'supported browser'? Internet Explorer 10 with JavaScript disabled? No Flash? Flash? Feature detection really is the best approach here, not browser-sniffing. Provide a fallback for browsers that do not support a feature. Browser sniffing will bring you into a lot of problems you'll have to keep a list of **every possible browser**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poking around online all the resources I've looked at say that you should essentially never use browser detect. It's better to test for features you know DO NOT exist in the browsers you can't support instead of trying to look at the user-agent string.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html (If you want to know whether the browser that views your page supports certain objects you want to use in your code, you should never EVER use a browser detect. )

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/ (Rather than using $.browser to detect the current user agent and alter the page presentation based on which browser is running, it is a good practice to use feature detection.)

So I think your approach with modernizer is probably the best.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a service.

The 'supported' list contains only those browser/device/OS combinations that you actually test.

The 'unsupported' list contains those browser/device/OS combinations that you know don't work (i.e, they failed your tests)

The 'might work' list is implicit as you've mentioned.